# Vertical navigation - Last dot is not active and add labels to each dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and javascript. I am having issues with vertical navigation.

The issue is: when I scroll down the page, all dots gets highlighted as expected except for the last dot. When the last dot is clicked, it will navigate to the last section, but remain un-highlighted.

```js
  $('.awesome-tooltip').tooltip({
    placement: 'left'
  });

  $(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
    dotnavigation();
  });

  function dotnavigation() {

    var numSections = $('.anchor').length;

    $('nav#dot-nav li a').removeClass('active').parent('li').removeClass('active');
    $('.TV').each(function(i, item) {
      var ele = $(item),
        nextTop;

      console.log(ele.next().html());

      if (typeof ele.next().offset() != "undefined") {
        nextTop = ele.next().offset().top;
      } else {
        nextTop = $(document).height();
      }

      if (ele.offset() !== null) {
        thisTop = ele.offset().top - ((nextTop - ele.offset().top) / numSections);
      } else {
        thisTop = 0;
      }

      var docTop = $(document).scrollTop();

      if (docTop >= thisTop && (docTop < nextTop)) {
        $('nav#dot-nav li').eq(i).addClass('active');
      }
    });
  }

  /* get clicks working */
  $('nav#dot-nav li').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).find('a').attr("href"),
      posi,
      ele,
      padding = 0;

    ele = $(id);
    posi = ($(ele).offset() || 0).top - padding;

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: posi
    }, 'slow');

    return false;
  });

  /* end dot nav */
```

```css
body {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.TV {
  padding: 13% 0;
  height: 100%;
}
nav#dot-nav {
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 999;
}

nav#dot-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
nav#dot-nav li {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  width: 10px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
nav#dot-nav li.active,
nav#dot-nav li:hover {
  background-color: red;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 transform: scale(1.5);
}

nav#dot-nav a {
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
}
.awesome-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {

  color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #8e44ad;
}
.awesome-tooltip + .tooltip.left > .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #8e44ad;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
 
 <nav data-spy="affix" id="dot-nav" >
    <ul>
      <li class="awesome-tooltip active" title="One"><a href="#One"></a></li>
      <li class="awesome-tooltip" title="Two"><a href="#Two"></a></li>
      <li class="awesome-tooltip" title="Three"><a href="#Three"></a></li>
      <li class="awesome-tooltip" title="Four"><a href="#Four"></a></li>
      <li class="awesome-tooltip" title="Five"><a href="#Five"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="TV">
    <div class="container">

      <a id="One" class="anchor"></a>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>One<small>Secondary text</small></h1>
          <p>
            This is a content.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="TV">
    <div class="container">
      <a id="Two" class="anchor"></a>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>two <small>Secondary text</small></h1>
          <p>
            This is a content.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="TV">
    <div class="container">
      <a id="Three" class="anchor"></a>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>three <small>Secondary text</small></h1>
          <p>
            This is a content.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="TV">
    <div class="container">
      <a id="Four" class="anchor"></a>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>four <small>Secondary text</small></h1>
          <p>
            This is a content.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="TV">
    <div class="container">
      <a id="Five" class="anchor"></a>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>five <small>Secondary text</small></h1>
          <p>
            This is a content.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Question 1) vertical navigation dot is not being activated when i hover mouse over the last dot in this page.

Question 2) i want to title to show in the text when i hover on the dots. is there a way that i can just show title next to dots in plain text?

https://jsfiddle.net/riodahamster/3ug0jnqv/

Comment: 0) in both snippet+fiddle, `.tooltip` isn't  working and stopping other code from working, removing that gives: 1) there appears to be no difference between dot 1 and dot 5 (guessing 5 is "last dot") 1) there's no "navigation" on "hover" only on click.  2) the "title=" tooltip works fine.

Comment: In your fiddle, you do this: load jquery 3.4.1 (fiddle options), load bootstrap, load jquery 1.11.1 (ie after boostrap.js).  This breaks the tooltip.  Remove the extra jquery and your tooltip works https://jsfiddle.net/L6w8zf95/.  You'll then need to describe the problem better.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I removed jquery 1.11.1 to avoid breaking and loaded bootstrap. Initially i had jquery 1.11.1 after bootstrap. But it was breaking.  The issue is, when I scroll down the page, all dots gets highlighted as expected except for the last dot. When the last dot is clicked, it will navigate to the last section, but remain un-highlighted. Title tooltip is working, but is there a way to remove the message icon outside the text and just have plain text when user is hovering the dot. I unable to make changes in.tooltip css.   https://jsfiddle.net/riodahamster/3ug0jnqv/11/

Comment: Remove the `$().tooltip` lines and you'll get the browser "plain text" tooltip - otherwise not really clear what you want done with the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
ele.next()
```

in the fiddle (at least), there is always something after the last .TV - in this case the script element.  So your code never recognises when it's the last .TV

To fix this you could:

- add a check in for "is last" or similar
- wrap all the .TV divs in another div and then the 5th will be the last, but may have other effects
- or you can use:

```
ele.next(".TV")
```

which will give you the next element and filter it to .TV (ie it does `ele.next().filter(".TV")` which will then give you null when it's the last, so your check for "undefined" will then kick in and your 5th node will work correctly.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0dfsLneq/

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I need to use bootstrap 4.1.3. I implemented bootstrap 4.1.3. I have set nav's position to absolute and made some changes to the bootstrap code. And navigation bar is stuck on the top and no longer moving as page scrolls. https://jsfiddle.net/riodahamster/uhvgxy7p/15/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add logic when

```
if(docTop == nextTop){
   $('nav#dot-nav li').eq(i+1).addClass('active');
 }
```

after

```
if (docTop >= thisTop && (docTop < nextTop)) {
   $('nav#dot-nav li').eq(i).addClass('active');
 }
```

may be it will resolve your problem.

N.B: in your fiddle tooltip not working and you didn't add $(document).ready